# Access macro not working unless VBA editor has been opened

Tags: ms-access

I have a Access database that has a form containing several controls with event-based macros (nothing too complicated). For some reason, when the database and the form is initially opened, the controls and macros are not working at all. However, after the VBA editor has been opened (at least once), everything works as intended.

I suspect that this problem is somehow related to security settings blocking any macros from running and the macros are enabled only after the VBA editor is open. There is no notification or anything mentioning of this. I have tried to fiddle with the settings, but so far no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you compile your Database? Did you double check access macro security settings, Enable all macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I eventually did, but the problem has fixed itself. I kept fiddling with the security settings, and it seems like that some of these settings take delayed effect, so it was hard to pinpoint exactly which of the selections eventually was the culprit of problem.